# How can I optimize this HashMap with 42,000 keys

Tags: java, arrays, hashmap

I have a csv file with 42,000 lines in the following pattern

```
03055,Milford,NH
03057,Mont Vernon,NH
03060,Nashua,NH
```

I tried to store the data in a `HashMap` using the zipcode as a key, like

```
while ((line = stream_in.readLine())!=null) {
    LocationBean temp_location_bean = new LocationBean();
    String line_trimmed = line.trim();
    String[] line_chunked = line_trimmed.split(",",4);
    temp_location_bean.setZip_code(line_chunked[0]);
    temp_location_bean.setCity(line_chunked[1]);
    temp_location_bean.setState(line_chunked[2]);
    this.locations_as_beans_list.put(zip_code, temp_location_bean);
}
```

But when I go to do a lookup:

```
 for(Map.Entry<String, LocationBean> location_object : this.locations_as_beans_list.entrySet())
 {
     LocationBean temp_location_bean = location_object.getValue();
     if (params[0].matches(temp_location_bean.getZip_code())) {
         master_location = temp_location_bean.getCity() + "," 
             + temp_location_bean.getState()
             + ", (" + temp_location_bean.getZip_code() +")";
     }
 }
```

It takes over 20 seconds.... Shouldn't the performance be relatively quick? How can I improve the performance here?

**tl;dr**
how can I optimize the reads in this example?

Comment: I don't understand why you just don't use this.locations_as_beans_list.get(params[0])?  That should either return null or the LocationBean you're looking for.

Comment: Isn't "locations_as_beans_list" a map? If yes, just use the key (zip code) to get the value? Why should you iterate through the entire collection?

Comment: I completely forgot about that. I've been using .entrySet() so much this week, that I never even considered the keys.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're looking for performance then you shouldn't iterate the `entrySet` to lookup a keyed zipcode. Instead, you might use the `HashMap` and get the value by its' key. Like,

```
LocationBean temp_location_bean = this.locations_as_beans_list.get(params[0]);
if (temp_location_bean != null) {
    master_location = temp_location_bean.getCity() + "," 
            + temp_location_bean.getState() 
            + ", (" + temp_location_bean.getZip_code() +")";
}
```

Comment: Oh ok, that makes since. I guess I'm so use to doing `.entrySet()`, that I never even considered the keys.

Comment: Took 1 second with your code, thanks a million dude!

Answer (score 4):

There can be many ways you can achieve performance optimization.
Here the question is not about whether you can achieve it through your data structure or data elements or data parsing.

There are various point you should remeber when optimization comes into picture, acheiving a performance boost is one of the most vital concern.

**1. Reading of file** - `BufferedReader` will take a constant amount of time of `6/7 seconds to parse 878 MB file`. How can you reduce it ?

*a.* You can go through `RandomAccessChannel API in java` which has reduced it to 0.16/0.19 seconds for the same file.

*b.* `Asynchronous File Reads` on a particular file.

**2. Dealing with data processing**

*a.* using Runtime available processor API's you can get the number of processor available on your particular machine and spawn that many threads for data processing.

*b.* Multi threading play's a major role in achieving performance

The above mentioned are few point you can spend time on to reduce the performcance

Comment: I think his problem is with the access, not the reading, though I agree with your suggestion to improve the file reading.  I liked your (a) apporach in section 2.

Comment: Yes the problem was with the access, not the reading. Thank you for the useful suggestions. This a quality answer for sure.

Answer (score 4):

The fundamental problem with the approach described in the question is, iterating over map and comparing every entry with query field. That's Wrong. HashMaps are primarily not meant for iteration and are optimized for search based on key. So the simplest trick to quickly gain performance, is to use the `key` and directly retrieve value using `get` method of HashMap (*Note the keys are hashed and hence calling get method with key will enable fast lookup*).

If you want to take one more step, you should look for specialized libraries like [Javolution](http://javolution.org/). The library makes sure that, instead of creating EntrySet for every item in the HashMap, it just stores entry using hashed keys. This results in significant improvement in memory as well as performance (*no new object creation for every entry*).

Answer (score 1):

If it is necessary to use regular expression based lookup, `HashMap` is not proper data structure to use. **List** can be a choice, because you have to use regular expression to match element in a loop.

My suggestion:

You could split your large data set into several Lists, and use **multiple thread** to search the lists respectively, and collect the results.

PLUS: MapReduce is little bit heavy for handling 40k data in a single machine I think.

Comment: For some reason he is using matches, so I'm not sure whether you can use  get() here

Answer (score 0):

Several suggestions here - 
A. Use something like Sharding - divide your data into several maps, run threads, and collect the result (think of it as a nice exercise in [MapReduce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce) 
B. Matches - why are using matches? there is performance hit there. 
Do you REALLY need to use something as generic is matchers?  write more specific code  for the matching algorithm 
C. In your EntrySet loop , where do you use getKey() ? why not just perform iteration over the values (look at [this method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#values%28%29))

Comment: Map Reduce fits for it perfectly.